# SharePoint CSOM list group by and filter

Tags: csom, caml-query, filter, caml

I have a list with columns "fruit" and "ripeness". Using csom, how can I return "Banana" where Yellow count >= 3?

```
ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext("https://sharepoint.blah.com");
List list = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Log");
ctx.Load(list);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
CamlQuery query = new CamlQuery();
ListItemCollection items = list.GetItems(query);
ctx.Load(items);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering that you have a column named 'Yellow' and typed number, and you wish to get all items have more then 3 in their 'Yellow ' column.

```
ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext("https://sharepoint.blah.com");
List list = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Log");
ctx.Load(list);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
CamlQuery query = new CamlQuery();
query.ViewXml
    = "<Where><Geq>"
    + "<FieldRef Name='Yellow'/><Value Type='Number'>"
    + "3</Value></Geq></Where>";
ListItemCollection items = list.GetItems(query);
ctx.Load(items);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```

Comment: Sorry... I want to show banana if there are >= 3 instances of Banana, Yellow.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use this kind of complex query is you don't have column 'Yellow' and its count. Assuming your ripeness column has value Yellow you can use below code.

```
ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext("https://sharepoint.blah.com");
List list = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Log");
ctx.Load(list);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
CamlQuery query = new CamlQuery();
query.ViewXml
    = "<Where><And>"
    + "<Eq><FieldRef Name='Fruit'/><Value Type='Text'>Banana</Value></Eq>"
    + "<Eq><FieldRef Name='Ripeness'/><Value Type='Text'>Yellow</Value></Eq>"
    + "</And></And></Where>";
ListItemCollection items = list.GetItems(query);
ctx.Load(items);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();

if(items.Count >=3)
{
    //use any one item from items object as items[0] - This will always be banana
    // display as you want
}
```